# Excel international date formatting

Tags: c++, excel, datetime, locale

I am having problems formatting Excel datetimes, so that it works internationally. Our program is written in C++ and uses COM to export data from our database to Excel, and this includes datetime fields.

If we don't supply a formatting mask, some installations of Excel displays these dates as Serial numbers (days since 1900.01.01 followed by time as a 24-hour fraction). This is unreadable to a human, so we ha found out that we MUST supply a date formatting mask to be sure that it displays readable.

The problem - as I see it - is that Excel uses international formatting masks. For example; the UK datetime format mask might be "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM".

But if the format mask is sent to an Excel that is installed in Sweden, it fails since the Swedish version of the Excel uses "ÅÅÅÅ-MM-DD tt:mm".

It's highly impractical to have 150 different national datetime formatting masks in our application to support different countries.

Is there a way to write formatting masks so that they include locale, such that we would be allowed to use ONE single mask?

Comment: Would it be possible to ask the OS or the Excel application what the localized long date mask is that it has and apply that?

Comment: From within Excel you can access both the local date format `NumberFormatLocal` and the US date format `NumberFormat`. If your C++ program can interact with Excel you could check for the `NumberFormatLocal` for a preset cell, or will you be running in circles this way?

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that. But I think it's also localized, so you have to ask for "Short date" if it's a US Excel, but "Kort datum" if it's a Swedish Excel, otherwise you get a rubbish answer. This is catch 22 so far. :)

Comment: K_B: I use Range->NumberFormat(), but the weird thing is that I cannot use a US date format there (which is not according to the documentation). If I do (PutNumberFormat(L"yyyy-mm-dd")), I get back dates as "yyyy-57-31" (57 is minute and 31 is day). The Excel documentation is very sparse on this -- it looks auto-generated by some tool.

Does anyone here know the difference between NumberFormat and NumberFormatLocal, and can explain it ??

Comment: @LasseSL500: What values do you put into the cells through the COM? Do you use the number of days since Excel epoch or do you set the cells to a string with the date?

Comment: wilx: it is stored in a COM variant with the type VT_DATE, which is the same as number of days since 1900.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are using the date functionality in Excel, the easiest way to handle this is to decide on a format and then create a string yourself in that format and set the cell accordingly.

This comic: http://xkcd.com/1179/  might help you choose a standard to go with.  Otherwise, clients that open your file in different countries will have differently formatted data.  Just pick a standard and force your data to that standard.

Edited to add:  There are libraries that can make this really easy for your as well... http://www.libxl.com/read-write-excel-date-time.html

Edited to add part2:  Basically what I'm trying to get at is to avoid asking for the asmk and just format the data yourself (if that makes sense).

Comment: The problem isn't actually formatting. Excel uses the formatting mask while parsing.

Comment: Right, but you are just exporting the data, so why does it matter, it should just be an fwrite() to a CSV file or something similar.  This will allow each cell to be treated as a string, and opening it in Excel will look the same regardless...

Comment: "look", yes, but that isn't a useful answer. Excel is generally used for calculations, and you cannot do calculations on random strings.

Comment: So now, I'm really lost, why do you care what the opened Excel file will look like when the data is presented, if the representation is the same?  The user can always reformat the cell using the Format Cell command.  The underlying data will remain unchanged, but worrying about what ti looks like due to their local settings should be outside the scope of your concerns.

Comment: Say I want to know what my average daily income is, which means summing income over a range and dividing it by the timespan. That timespan is a difference between two dates. If you'd export pre-formatted date strings to Excel, Excel can't calculate a timespan given two strings.

Comment: Thanks for your response, and I agree. I was thinking about defining the column as just text for Excel, and to use the built-in C string functions to format the date (for example strftime). But then our customers would not be able to calculate dates on it. For example; if I export the date as 2004-05-28 (28:th May 2004) and then Formats the cell as date in Excel, it converts it to 1905 something (treats 2004 as a serial number obviously). Hmmmm.

Comment: MSalters: The problem IS formatting the display mask. Internally, I convert the date to a Variant and then uses this Variant to SafeArrayPutElement() to Excel. So Excel knows it's a date, there is no problem in parsing it. And in 95% of all Excel installations the date is formatted OK. However, in some Excel installations it's just displayed as a serial number (of for me unknown reasons).

That's why I need to explicitly format the column, and this is when I get into problems: because I cannot find a formatting mask that displays a date in the current locale, regardless of which.

Comment: I must have misunderstood something. Can it be this complicated? :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend doing the following: Create an excel with date formatting on a specific cell and save this for your program to use.

Now when the program runs it will open this use this excel file to retrieve the local date formatting from the excel and the specified cell.

When you have multiple formats to save just use different cells for them.

It is not a nice way but will work afaik.

Alteratively you could consider creating an xla(m) file that will use vba and a command to feed back the local formatting characters through a function like:

```
Public Function localChar(charIn As Range) As String
    localChar = charIn.NumberFormatLocal
End Function
```

Also not a very clean method, but it might do the trick for you.